# PHP add code to every new page

Tags: php, include

I am adding some `include("file.php");` to several php pages.

Is there any way to be sure the include is added to every PHP page I create so I don't need to manually add those lines of code and also to prevent human error. If it is not possible to automatically do this, what would be the best way to achieve this.

I need to do this so I can do something like checking it the user is already authenticated then continue if not then redirect to the login page.

Comment: If the PHP are classes, checkout `__autoload` feature in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use **[auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)**. Set this directive in your php.ini or .htaccess file to the path to your file.php file and any PHP file accessed will automatically have the contents of the config file prepended to it.

For `.htaccess`

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /full/path/to/file/file.php
```

or Try this

```
foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this is an overkill. I would recommend a `require.php` containing all paths of `php` required to load and use `__autoload` feature.

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP are OOP classes & PHP 5 is used, here is a way to load classes ONLY when they are needed:

```
$class_dir = array(
    'some/class/path/model/',
    'some/class/path/dao/',
    'some/class/path/service/',
);
function __autoload($class_name) {
    global $class_dir;
    foreach ($class_dir as $directory) {
        if (file_exists($directory . $class_name . '.php')) {
            require_once($directory . $class_name . '.php');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [PHP 5 Autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot but they are not classes so I will mark the other answer as correct but yours is correct too. Really thanks a lot.